# Limit NumericUpDown Value depending on Value selected from DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, numericupdown

How can I limit max int that can be entered into my `NumericUpDown`(nudqty). my code works it limits the value when I change it using up down arrows, but when I type it's not. suggestions please and tell me if it's not possible in `NumericUpDown` and just change it to `TextBox`.

```
private void dgv1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    lblqty.Text = dgv1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    nudqty.Maximum = Convert.ToDecimal(lblqty.Text); 
}
```

[image: my form]

Comment: NUD does not validate what you entered until after it knows for a fact that you are done typing.  Since you might type "100" and press the Backspace key to correct the extra "0".  The only way it can know that fact is when NUD loses the focus.  Inevitably the Maximum property value doesn't get applied until you press the Add button.  A workaround would be to use the Validating event and not set a Maximum, lets you complain.  But, really, just make sure that the user can easily correct mistakes in the cart as well.

Comment: The `Maximum` applies on the control when the control loses focus or when the user clicks on up/down button or when the user uses keyboard arrow keys to change the value. And in all cases when you ask the `Value` from the control the `Maximum` will be applied and then the value will be returned to you. So don't worry about the text which the user types. Set `Maximum` property and you will get a valid value all times if you use `Value` property.

Comment: @HansPassant can you show me a sample code using Validating? I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `SelectionMode` of `DataGridView` to `FullRowSelect` and then handle  [`SelectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DataGridView`. In the event after finding the value using [`CurrentRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow(v=vs.110).aspx), reset the `Value` of `NumericUpDown` to 0 and set its [`Maximum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.maximum(v=vs.110).aspx) to the extracted value:

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int max = (int)this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value;
    this.numericUpDown1.Value = 0;
    this.numericUpDown1.Maximum = max;
}
```

Comment: Just realized my NUD value resets to the Maximum I set it into even when I enter values greater than the Maximum. If I don't find other solution, then I guess I'll just stick with this (and mark your answer). Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to be worry about `Value` when you set `Maximum` and read `Value`. All other solutions which you may think about them, need to perform a validation using `Maximum` property, while the `Maximum` property performs it for you I don't have any idea about why another approach may be useful.